# Prove the limit of $f (x)$ is $0$ under the conditions:

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Suppose the function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ has the property that there is some $M > 0$ such that

$|f(x)| \leq M|x|^2~\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Prove that

$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0$.

---

Not sure how to start, would really appreciate a hint as to what's to be done. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** We have $-Mx^2\le f(x)-0\le Mx^2$. Now Squeeze.

For an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ version, we can let $\delta=\min(1, \epsilon/M)$.

Comment: So by the squeezing principle if Mx^2 and -Mx^2 converge to the same value (which if we let x = 0, that value will be 0) then f(x) will also converge to that value, which will be it's limit? Sorry, I'm sure this is pretty elementary stuff but I'm really struggling in this subject and am working on additional problems to try and strengthen my understanding. Unless I'm mistaken, I think I've got it (though I'm not entirely certain how f(x) got bounded by Mx^2 and -Mx^2). Thanks for your help.

Comment: For the bound, the given condition $|f(x)|\le Mx^2$ says that $-Mx^2\le f(x)\le Mx^2$. I don't know the level/style of your course, so I do not know whether a squeezing argument or the more formal and basic $\epsilon$-$\delta$ is expected.